# Preencher Select Automaticamente por meio de If e else com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Estou precisando de uma ajuda. Tenho um formulário que capta informações de endereço através do cep.

Eu preciso de uma função em Jquery que vai selecionar um campo em um select dependendo do valor preenchido automaticamente no input com id `estado`. Veja como tentei porém não funciona:

```
$("#estado").val(dados.uf); // preenche o input estado automaticamente (funciona)
var estado = this.val(dados.uf); // aqui quero pegar o valor preenchido para selecionar automaticamente o select com id `selecione-estado`
if(estado == 'SP') {
    $("#selecione-estado option[data-sigla='SP']").prop("selected", true);
}
else if(estado == 'GO') {
    $("#selecione-estado option[data-sigla='GO']").prop("selected", true);
}
```

O meu `select`está assim:

```
<select name="zone_id" id="selecione-estado" class="form-control" data-value="" data-cep="uf">
    <option value="" data-sigla=''> --- Selecione --- </option>
    <option value="440" data-sigla='AC'>Acre</option>
    <option value="441" data-sigla='AL'>Alagoas</option>
    <option value="442" data-sigla='AP'>Amapá</option>
    <option value="443" data-sigla='AM'>Amazonas</option>
    <option value="444" data-sigla='BA'>Bahia</option>
    <option value="445" data-sigla='CE'>Ceará</option>
    <option value="446" data-sigla='DF'>Distrito Federal</option>
    <option value="447" data-sigla='ES'>Espírito Santo</option>
    <option value="448" data-sigla='GO'>Goiás</option>
    <option value="449" data-sigla='MA'>Maranhão</option>
    <option value="450" data-sigla='MT'>Mato Grosso</option>
    <option value="451" data-sigla='MS'>Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
    <option value="452" data-sigla='MG'>Minas Gerais</option>
    <option value="453" data-sigla='PA'>Pará</option>
    <option value="454" data-sigla='PB'>Paraíba</option>
    <option value="455" data-sigla='PR'>Paraná</option>
    <option value="456" data-sigla='PE'>Pernambuco</option>
    <option value="457" data-sigla='PI'>Piauí</option>
    <option value="458" data-sigla='RJ'>Rio de Janeiro</option>
    <option value="459" data-sigla='RN'>Rio Grande do Norte</option>
    <option value="460" data-sigla='RS'>Rio Grande do Sul</option>
    <option value="461" data-sigla='RO'>Rondônia</option>
    <option value="462" data-sigla='RR'>Roraima</option>
    <option value="463" data-sigla='SC'>Santa Catarina</option>
    <option value="464" data-sigla='SP'>São Paulo</option>
    <option value="465" data-sigla='SE'>Sergipe</option>
    <option value="466" data-sigla='TO'>Tocantins</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

faça da seguinte forma:

```js
var data = { uf: 'SP' };
var estado = $("#estado");
var select = $("#selecione-estado");
var option = $("option[data-sigla='" + data.uf + "']");
estado.val(data.uf);
select.val(option.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="estado" type="text" />
<select name="zone_id" id="selecione-estado" class="form-control" data-value="" data-cep="uf">
  <option value="" data-sigla=''> --- Selecione --- </option>
  <option value="440" data-sigla='AC'>Acre</option>
  <option value="441" data-sigla='AL'>Alagoas</option>
  <option value="442" data-sigla='AP'>Amapá</option>
  <option value="443" data-sigla='AM'>Amazonas</option>
  <option value="444" data-sigla='BA'>Bahia</option>
  <option value="445" data-sigla='CE'>Ceará</option>
  <option value="446" data-sigla='DF'>Distrito Federal</option>
  <option value="447" data-sigla='ES'>Espírito Santo</option>
  <option value="448" data-sigla='GO'>Goiás</option>
  <option value="449" data-sigla='MA'>Maranhão</option>
  <option value="450" data-sigla='MT'>Mato Grosso</option>
  <option value="451" data-sigla='MS'>Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
  <option value="452" data-sigla='MG'>Minas Gerais</option>
  <option value="453" data-sigla='PA'>Pará</option>
  <option value="454" data-sigla='PB'>Paraíba</option>
  <option value="455" data-sigla='PR'>Paraná</option>
  <option value="456" data-sigla='PE'>Pernambuco</option>
  <option value="457" data-sigla='PI'>Piauí</option>
  <option value="458" data-sigla='RJ'>Rio de Janeiro</option>
  <option value="459" data-sigla='RN'>Rio Grande do Norte</option>
  <option value="460" data-sigla='RS'>Rio Grande do Sul</option>
  <option value="461" data-sigla='RO'>Rondônia</option>
  <option value="462" data-sigla='RR'>Roraima</option>
  <option value="463" data-sigla='SC'>Santa Catarina</option>
  <option value="464" data-sigla='SP'>São Paulo</option>
  <option value="465" data-sigla='SE'>Sergipe</option>
  <option value="466" data-sigla='TO'>Tocantins</option>
</select>
```

**P.S.:** não é necessario setar o `selected` do `option`.

Comment: Perfeito. Desta forma encurtou o código e executou o que eu precisava!